# Find the limit of the sequence $\bigg\{\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(1+x^i)\bigg\}_{n=1}^\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus

The problem is as it follows: find the limit of the sequence $\bigg\{\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(1+x^i)\bigg\}_{n=1}^\infty$ as $n\to\infty, |x|<1$. What I did is to expand it and got the following sum: $1+x+x^2+2x^3+2x^4+...+nx^{2n-1}+nx^{2n}+......+x^{2n^2+n}\\$
and tried to group up the members to get a number of geometric progressions that converge as $|x|<1$. The problem is that I can't seem to find the limit with my approach. Maybe I should try something different.

Comment: How about taking $\log$?

Comment: I did that and can't seem to find what to do with the sum I got

Comment: If $x\in(0,1)$ use $0<\log(1+x^i)<x^i$ so your series has terms bounded above by $\sum x^i$

Comment: That proves that the sequence is convergent, but it doesn't help to find the limit (or the sum of the new sequence), It would only mean that the sum is somewhere between 0 and $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Ah yes. I’d forgotten that you wanted the limit. I don’t suppose adding another term to the Taylor series of log would give you a useful lower bound? Other than that I’m stuck.

Comment: For positive $x$ I can get a lower bound that has a sum equal to the geometric progression that bounds it above. We have that the product is equal to $1+x+x^2+2x^3+2x^4+...+nx^{2n-1}+nx^{2n}+......+x^{2n^2+n}\\$ and if I remove some of the members to get a geometric progression as they are all positive I would get something less, $$\sum_{i=0}^{2n^2+2}x^i \leq \prod_{i=1}^{2n}(1+x^i) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{2n}x^i$$ and as both the left and the right limits are $\frac{1}{1-x}$ we get that the limit we were looking for is $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but what to do if $x$ is negative?

Comment: If $x=0$ it should be easy. Perhaps if $x<0$ you can split your sum into the negative part and positive part and find those limits separately

Comment: So, it turned out that there was a mistake in the problem - it should only include multipliers in the form $(1+x^{2^i})$, and it becomes an easy problem - if you multiply it by $(1-x)$ you get $\frac{1-x^{4^n}}{1-x}$ and that converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$.